# What is the image of L-parameter on inertia subgroup?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $F$ be a local field. Is there any reference talking about the the image of L-parameter on inertia subgroup $I_F$ of Weil group $W_F$? Many Thanks!

Comment: You may want to think about the case of an $L$-parameter into $GL_1$ and $GL_2$ first, before you think about more general cases.  The key input is the structure of the intertia group, which you can find in Serre's *Local fields*.  Tate's article in the *Corvalis* proceedings will give you some additional hints.  Regards, 

Comment: Thanks, Emerton. I have read a part of Bushnell-Henniart's book on $GL_2$ and know the structure of inertia group. Indeed, I would like to know that what is the motivation to think about the image of it and the centralizer of it. For example, in Arthur's new book (The endoscopic classification....) and his past papers, and other people's works, they defined a special $\mathcal{S}$-group. Cheers!